# Adjusted R^2 value

Tags: statistics, regression

Could somebody explain whether a small value of adjusted R^2 - say 0.04 means that the regression model is not good at explaining the variation of Y variables? I though this may depend on the number of X variables in the model, but then adjusted R^2 value takes that into account?
 If that is the case, what is the rule of thumb when evaluating the value of adjusted R^2?

Many thanks.

Comment: There is no right answer about 'is my r-squared (or adjusted r-square) high enough?'. You should probably check the following link: http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics-2/how-high-should-r-squared-be-in-regression-analysis